# Pass by reference and value in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a test case as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var arrayList=[{"name":"pradip"},{"name":"Tengi"}];
   var del = function(list) {
      list.splice(1,1);
      $("div").append("function:" + list.length +"<br>"); 
   };
   $("div").append("original:" + arrayList.length+"<br>");
   del(arrayList);
   $("div").append("modified"+ arrayList.length+"<br>");

   var test=1;
   var increase=function(a){
      a++;
      $("div").append("function="+a+"<br>");
   }
   $("div").append("original test="+test+"<br>");
   increase(test);
   $("div").append("increased test="+test+"<br>"); 
});
```

The output is :

```
original:2
function:1
modified1
original test=1
function=2
increased test=1
```

When I pass array to a function by value, and in the function I change the value, the change is also reflected in the original array but in other case, there is no change.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bs6d88hd/)

Why is the pass by value acting as if it is pass by reference for array ?

Comment: JavaScript has only pass-by-value. In cases of objects, the value is a actually a *reference* to the object. *Pass-by-reference* is something different: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a reference to the array by value.

You now have two references to the same array instance.

If you don't want the array to change, you need to explicitly create a copy .

Answer (score -1):

if the passed argument **is a primitive type** like (**string** ,**number**)
then  a copy of the passed parameter  is created (destroyed when the function call is finished) **which means passage by value**

but if the **passed argument** is **an object** or **an array** then we have   **passage  by** **reference**

here is an example

```
num = 10;
str = 'string';
arr = [1,2,3]
obj = {p1:'val1'}

function passedBy(arg1){
  if(typeof arg1 === 'object'){
    // we are in the case where arg1 can be an object or an array 
       if(arg1.constructor === Array){
          // add 1 to the passed array 
          arg1.push(1);
       }else{
           // add p2 property to the passed object
           arg1.p2 = 'val2';

      }

  }else{
      //here arg1 parameter is a string or a number
      // if arg1 is a string the following instruction should perform a concatenation     
      // operation instead it should add 1 to arg1
      arg1 +=1 
  }

}
```

now you can try this simple function to see the difference between passage by reference and passage by value

for example

```
passedBy(num);  
passedBy(str); 
console.log(num);
console.log(str);
```

we can see easily that the value of **str** and **num** is not changed even though we modified them inside the passedBy() function

BUT IF WE TRY

```
passedBy(arr);
passedBy(obj);
console.log(arr);
console.log(obj);
```

we can see clearly 
that the content of **arr** and **obj** in not the same as the initial one

HOPE YOU GET IT

Comment: No, there is no pass by reference in JavaScript.

Comment: try to pass an object to a function and inside the function try modify    the object (for example add new property ) and after try to display the old object(the one passed as an argument) you will obtain a a new property added to the initial object, so what you call this ?

Comment: This is pass by value. You cannot "pass an object" in JavaScript. Objects are not values in JavaScript. The only types in JavaScript are primitives and references (pointers to objects). You are passing a pointer by value. It's exactly the same as Java, which is also only pass by value.